# Woocommerce Кнопка "в корзину" возле каждой цены

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

По умолчанию, если указывать несколько цен в Вариациях, то на странице товара они будут выводиться, как селект. Выбираем нужную и в корзину.

Нужно реализовать так, чтобы не было селекта, отображалась каждая цена, а рядом кнопка "в корзину". А так же, вывести это все не на страницу товара, а в карточку товара.

Цены получаю так:

Хотелось бы вместо 41, динамически получать id поля из вариации

```
$variation_price3 = get_variation_price_by_id($product_id, 41);
echo $variation_price3->display_regular_price;
echo $variation_price3->display_price;



function get_variation_price_by_id($product_id, $variation_id)
{
    $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
    $product = new WC_Product_Variable($product_id);
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $var_data = [];
    foreach ($variations as $variation) {
        if ($variation['variation_id'] == $variation_id) {
            $display_regular_price = $variation['display_regular_price'] . '<span class="currency">' . $currency_symbol . '</span>';
            $display_price = $variation['display_price'] . '<span class="currency">' . $currency_symbol . '</span>';
        }
    }

    //Check if Regular price is equal with Sale price (Display price)
    if ($display_regular_price == $display_price) {
        $display_price = false;
    }

    $priceArray = array(
        'display_regular_price' => $display_regular_price,
        'display_price' => $display_price
    );
    $priceObject = (object) $priceArray;
    return $priceObject;
}
```

Comment: Я вижу костыли в костылях и не понимаю что сложного сделать в товаре проверку на тип товара и если это вариативный товар, то получить его вариации через функцию get_available_variations() - данные цены там уже включены

Comment: @noname228 
$tickets = new WC_Product_Variable($product_id); $variables = $tickets->get_available_variations(); - вместо 41 ничего не выводит.

Comment: Значит у товара одна вариация

Comment: @noname228 нет, их там 3